# How to remove a screen from stack navigation React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have stack A->B->C->D
When position in D, I want remove C to back from D->B
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution,
 if you want to go back twice in a stack: `this.props.navigation.pop(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this is if you want to navigate from D to B, you can use `navigation.navigate('B')` ([navigate prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/)) from the screen D.

Comment: this will go to B with new route params, hence it can cause some re-render, just use pop(2) to back to B